# Transformation matrix for rotation by angle theta

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Find the standard matrix of the transformation T: R3 → R3 that corresponds to the anti-clockwise rotation by an angle θ about the x1-axis.

I have no idea how to even begin to approach this problem. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Look at what the transformation does to your unit vectors.

Comment: Do you understand what component is unchanged by the rotation?

Comment: yes, @RobertTheTutor, I get that the transformation will rotate around the x axis and thus all the values lying on that axis will remain unchanged, however, I do not understand how I might go about creating a transformation matrix, particularly with a variable that related to the angle theta. (also @Jonah)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & a & b\\ 0 & c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
Is how you deal with the fixed axis $x$.  The four values $a,b,c,d$ need to describe the two dimensional rotation that results when you ignore the $x$ component.  This $2x2$ sub matrix has a standard form involving  $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks tho @RobertTheTutor.
If anyone is reading this in the future, (a=cos(t), b=-sin(t), c=sin(t), d=cos(t)) where t = theta.